# jsonpath read does not work with json in String representation

Tags: json, maven, jsonpath

I have a JSON represented in String format like shown below and i am using jsonpath.read method to find the pattern i am looking for.

```
    String jsonExpr="{\"store\":"
             +"{"
               +"\"book\":"
                 +"   [ "
                   +"     { \"category\": \"reference\","
                     +"     \"author\": \"Nigel Rees\","
                       +"   \"title\": \"Sayings of the Century\","
                         +" \"price\": 8.95"
                        +"},"
                        +"{ \"category\": \"fiction\","
                         +" \"author\": \"Evelyn Waugh\","
                          +"\"title\": \"Sword of Honour\","
                          +"\"price\": 12.99"
                        +"},"
                        +"{ \"category\": \"fiction\","
                         +" \"author\": \"Herman Melville\","
                          +"\"title\": \"Moby Dick\","
                          +"\"isbn\": \"0-553-21311-3\","
                          +"\"price\": 8.99"
                        +"},"
                        +"{ \"category\": \"fiction\","
                          +"\"author\": \"J. R. R. Tolkien\","
                          +"\"title\": \"The Lord of the Rings\","
                          +"\"isbn\": \"0-395-19395-8\","
                          +"\"price\": 22.99"
                        +"}"
                    +"],"
                    +"\"bicycle\":"
                    +"{"
                       +" \"color\": \"red\","
                        +"\"price\": 19.95,"
                    +"}"
                +"}"
            +"}";
```

And here is the pattern i am trying to find the json .

```
        String matchString="$.store";

            String matchValue = JsonPath.read("'"+jsonExpr+"'",matchString).toString();
                            System.out.println(" Printing matched value "+matchValue);
```

But i am getting exception stating that property not found in path and only $ pattern works which prints the entire JSON. Using build 1.2.0 through maven.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Property ['store'] not found in path $
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.token.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:41)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.token.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:53)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:53)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:61)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:179)
```

Comment: I also faced a same issue. I put the json in the file, and read the text file, and then used read() method and that worked :). I know I am very late, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Map<String, Object> result = JsonPath.read(jsonExpr, "$.store");
```

Or check out the doc [here](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath).